# Disable admin bar is not working in wordpress 4.8

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.8

I have tried with `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');`
   in wordpress 4.8 version and its not hiding the admin bar.

Help me with a solution.

Comment: It should work, I have tried this now and working fine, or you try this one

show_admin_bar(false);

Comment: you are in admin side or client side ? if you are in admin side, it should be seen and that is expected .

Comment: @Ashkar ,I tried with your code also it is not working.!!

Comment: You are pasting this code in function.php file right? It should work.

Comment: yes in theme functions.php, it is not working

Comment: No idea then, is there any condition before this code?

Comment: no condition ,just i put show_admin_bar(false); in end of functions.php file

Answer (score 16):

Try add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false', PHP_INT_MAX );

Comment: What does`PHP_INT_MAX` means? and why does `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');` doesn't work?

Comment: I think that the trick here si that the third parameter of `add_filter`is supposed to be an int representing the priority of the filter. From the doc : `$priority
(int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.` So using PHP_INT_MAX means using the maximum numeric value avaiable. 9999 would have made the trick.

Comment: Why is `show_admin_bar(false)` not working? According to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/show_admin_bar/ this function should work if I simply put it in the `function.php`

Answer (score 6):

Try this to remove admin bar for all roles except administrator

```
function remove_admin_bar()
{
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'remove_admin_bar', PHP_INT_MAX);
```